# SQL query not working on Google BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

When I try this query on Google Bigquery, I get the following error:

```
"SELECT query which references non constant fields or uses aggregation functions or has one or more of WHERE, OMIT IF, GROUP
 BY, ORDER BY clauses must have FROM clause."
```

What is happening?

```
SELECT fq.ds_id AS ds_id,
       fq.dm_id AS dm_id,
       fq.freq AS freq,
       rc.rec AS rec,
       rd.reg AS reg
FROM dataset.table_fq_ds fq
  INNER JOIN EACH dataset.table_rc_ds rc ON (fq.ds_id = rc.ds_id)
  INNER JOIN EACH dataset.table_rd_ds rd ON (fq.ds_id = rd.ds_id);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope below will help in troubleshooting

First SELECT works perfectly whereas second one gives exactly same error

**"Correct" version**

```
SELECT 
  fq.ds_id AS ds_id,
  fq.dm_id AS dm_id,
  fq.freq AS freq,
  rc.rec AS rec,
  rd.reg AS reg
FROM ( SELECT 1 AS ds_id, 11 AS dm_id, 12 AS freq) fq
INNER JOIN EACH (SELECT 1 AS ds_id, 22 AS rec) rc ON (fq.ds_id = rc.ds_id)
INNER JOIN EACH (SELECT 1 AS ds_id, 33 AS reg) rd ON (fq.ds_id = rd.ds_id);

ds_id   dm_id   freq    rec reg  
    1      11     12     22  33
```

**Version with Error**  - change is only in first INNER:
*SELECT ds_id vs SELECT 1 AS ds_id*

```
SELECT 
  fq.ds_id AS ds_id,
  fq.dm_id AS dm_id,
  fq.freq AS freq,
  rc.rec AS rec,
  rd.reg AS reg
FROM ( SELECT 1 AS ds_id, 11 AS dm_id, 12 AS freq) fq
INNER JOIN EACH (SELECT ds_id, 22 AS rec) rc ON (fq.ds_id = rc.ds_id)
INNER JOIN EACH (SELECT 1 AS ds_id, 33 AS reg) rd ON (fq.ds_id = rd.ds_id);
```

> Error: SELECT query which references non constant fields or uses
>   aggregation functions or has one or more of WHERE, OMIT IF, GROUP BY,
>   ORDER BY clauses must have FROM clause.

Comment: Your second query seems like it's actually correctly an error -- `SELECT ds_id, 22 AS rec` refers to the field `ds_id` but doesn't give it a constant value or say what table it's from.

Comment: this is exactly the point  - to show how such error can be introduced

Comment: Sorry I dont understand your answer, I can't see my dataset.tables anymore in your code. I don't think there is nothing wrong with my query. I think this is more a bigquery bug.

Comment: i tried to present scenario when error is introduced by user by let's say skipping somehow actual value. If you still think it is BigQuery bug - it is a possibility  - check https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=351